# Animation triggered by scroll is very slow

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, carousel

I'm working on a carousel that locks the the top of the page upon scrolling to a certain point. In order for it to look good on when its locked, I need to make the current selected image, the size of the other images that aren't selected. I've completed it just fine using straight css, but I'd rather have an animation to make for a smoother transition. I have the following code, but its extremely slow. I mean REALLY slooooow.Its set to take .2 seconds, but it takes around 20 seconds, sometimes longer. Am I doing something wrong here?

HTML -

```
<li class="active" style="width: 282px; margin-top: 0px;">
 <a data-slideindex="0" href="#">
  <div class="carousel-photo faded" style="height: 282px; width: 282px; background-image: url("images/photos/featured11.jpg");">
    <img class="photo" src="images/photos/featured11.jpg" style="display: none;">
  </div>
  <span class="name" style="width: 282px; font-size: 2.25em; margin-top: 15px; text-transform: uppercase;">John Doe</span>
  <span class="member-date" style="width: 282px; font-size: 1em;">11/26/2002</span>
 </a>
</li>
```

jQuery -

```
  $('.carousel-wrap .active').animate({ width: '155px', marginTop: '64px', marginRight: '0px' }, 200);
  $('.carousel-wrap .active .carousel-photo').animate({'height': '155px', 'width': '155px'}, 200);
  $('.carousel-wrap .active .name').animate({ width: '155px', fontSize: '.9375em', marginTop: '8px', 'text-transform': 'none'}, 200);
  $('.carousel-wrap .active .name').css({ 'text-transform': 'none' });
  $('.carousel-wrap .active .member-date').animate({ width: '155px', fontSize: '.75em' }, 200);
```

This is triggered when scrolling past a point, but is set to only execute once, so its not being called on a bunch of times.

Comment: you're executing `animate()` concurrently that makes it slow i think.. is finishing an animation after another is not an option?

Comment: Even if I only use even one animate() its slow as a dog. Its a 30kb .js file, but I don't think that would be the issue.

Comment: Try using CSS transition instead of animate() ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting it to be triggered? Are you sure it's only been called once? Even so, when using animation that is called by events, is a good practice to stop any previously animations that might still be running on the element. You can do it like this:

```
$('.carousel-wrap .active').stop().animate({ width: '155px', marginTop: '64px', marginRight: '0px' }, 200);
```